# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (2k+1)\,x^{2k}$,$\,$ for $|x| < 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let $f(x)$ be $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{2k+1}$. This sum equals $$x + x^3 + x^5 + \dots - x= x(1 + x^2 + (x^2)^2 + \dots) - x = \frac{x}{1-x^2} - x = \frac{x^3}{1-x^2}$$

Now, okay, the original sum is the derivative of $f$, but I don't think it is the conclusion the author expected...?

Comment: I think that is the expected conclusion.

Comment: Actualy, I think you are expected to compute that derivative.

Comment: Okay, since this exercise (from "Introduction to algorithms" (Cormen et al.)) is star-marked, I expected something more difficult. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are allowed to differentiate, as $f(x)$ is differentiable for every $|x|<1$.

Then
$$
f'(x)=\frac{3x^2}{1-x^2}+\frac{2x^4}{(1-x^2)^2}.
$$